# __doc__ is None with method but not with function

Tags: python, decorator

I have to decorate some python methods and functions. Unfortunetly the **doc** attribute to get the docstring of the original function doesn't work if the function is a method.

> To avoid confusion here a remenber:
> a function is series of instructions (e.g.`def function(arg)`)
> a method is function bind to a class (e.g.`def methog(self, arg)`)

Is it a normal behaviour or a bug ?

```python
class GruiMethod:
    def __init__(self, callable_):
        self._instance = None
        self.real_callable = callable_

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # We save the instance of the object from the method class. In case the function is a method
        self._instance = instance
        return self.__call__

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Invoked on every call of any decorated method
        if self._instance:
            return self.real_callable(self._instance, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.real_callable(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def __doc__(self):
        return self.real_callable.__doc__

    # ...

def my_decorator(func):
    t = GruiMethod(func)
    print("Test", t.__doc__) # It actually print the rigth doc
    return t


class Foo:
    @my_decorator
    def bar(self, message):
        """This method return a welcome message"""
        return "Hello %s: %s" % (self._people, message)


@my_decorator
def my_function(message):
    """This function return a welcome message"""
    return "::%s::" % message


class TestDecorator(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_doc_attr(self):
        self.assertEqual("This function return a welcome message", my_function.__doc__) # Works
        self.assertEqual("This is a simple class to run unit test", Foo.__doc__) # Works
        self.assertEqual("This method return a welcome message", Foo().bar.__doc__) # Fail __doc__ is None
```

Comment: Method docstrings work fine. Your decorator is causing this issue. `bar` is replaced by the decorator value which doesn't have a doc string. You will see it if you give `__call__()` a doc string.

Comment: I don't want to get the __call__ docstring. I want to get the docstring from the decorated method

Comment: Then you should look at `functools.wraps`. I think it can help, but you might need a little refactoring.

Comment: Can not use it as I am returning a custom class instead of a function. And returning a function doesn't really match with the requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It is quite obvious actualy...
Returning the instance itself not the `__call__` method solve the problem. I don't know why the behaviour is different when the decorator is bound to a method but If anyone have a explaination they are welcome to comment

```py
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    self._instance = instance
    self._owner = owner
    return self
```